# 406 error on ajax calls in Drupal 8

Tags: ajax, 8, routes

Yesterday I upgraded from drupal 8 beta 3 to beta 10. I noticed all my ajax calls are now getting error 406 (Not acceptable).

This is my route:

```
switch_customer.user:
  path: '/profile/get/{template}'
  defaults:
    _controller: 'Drupal\switch_customer\Controller\CustomerController::renderDisplay'
    _title: 'User Info'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

Controller:

```
$content = array(
            '#theme' => $templateName,
            '#items' => $items
        );

        $content = render($content);
        return $content;
```

Ajax call:

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/profile/get/info',
        success: function (data) {
           jQuery(".profile-sidebar-info").empty().append(data);
            if(cb){
                cb();
            }
        }
    });
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong? All my calls were fine in the previous beta. Can someone assist me?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you access the ajax callback directly with your browser? I.e. copy+paste the URL to the Ajax callback into the address bar.

Comment: I removed the render function as mentioned below, and I still get a 406. When I access the ajax callback directly I get the full page, without errors. If I run the array through the render function first, I get Not Acceptable even if I access the ajax callback directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller must return an array or a Response object.

If you want to return the content as-is (no "drupal" around it):

```
return new Response($content)
```

If you want to return a normal, full page, then just return the render array.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Could you elaborate? I tried returning the array ($content) instead of rendering it first, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Just don't call render(), return $content as a render array.

Comment: @Berdir: The OP tries to return a HTML fragment (not the whole page) from an Ajax callback. If the controller returns a render array, a complete page will be generated.

Comment: Right. Then you need new Response(render($content)) :)

Answer (score 0):

Always return the Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse

```
class MyController extends ControllerBase {
  public function handleAjax(Request $request) {
    $string = $request->query->get('something');
    render($output);
    return new JsonResponse($output);
  }
}
```

Comment: In your case probably use something like end(explode('/', $request->getPathInfo())).